# Split up a wordpress post text into 2

Tags: wordpress, post

I would like to display a wordpress post in 3 parts:

- Title
- First 50 words of the post main text.
- The main post text removing the first 50 words (as they will already be shown)

what I'm not sure on is how to show just the first 50 words, and then exclude those first 50 words from the main post text that I want to display below.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the first 50 *words* and not the first 50 *characters*:

```
$title = $post->post_title;

$words = explode(' ', $post->post_content);

if(count($words) > 50) {
    $first_fifty = array_slice($words, 0, 50);
    $remaining   = array_slice($words, 50);
}
```